# Additional fields MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have table `UserProfile`, where I have some additional fields, as email, typeAccount, isActivated etc.
When I get `Membership.GetUser().(..)`, I don't have these fields. 
How to resolve it? And how to change value of this fields?

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int typeAccount { get; set; }
    public bool activated { get; set; }
    public string activationcode { get; set; }
    public bool del { get; set; }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Did you add the membership provider tables?

Comment: I worked with this tutorial - http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/

Comment: You should accept Darin's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The membership provider is not handling profiles. If you want to retrieve the UserProfile record of the currently authenticated user simply use the context:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
    {
        UserProfile user = db
            .UserProfiles
            .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

        // do something with the profile
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfecty! Now I return all UserProfile, thanks! :) And can you tell me, how for example change typeAccount in this method for some UserName ?

Comment: You first retrieve the UserProfile (with the method I have shown in my answer), then you modify the value of the typeAccount property (for example `user.typeAccount = 123;`) and finally you call the SaveChanges method on the data context (`db.SaveChanges();`).